# -insertSections:withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationTop affect tableHeaderView

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I'm trying to insert section 0 using -insertSections:withRowAnimation: with UITableViewRowAnimationTop tableHeaderView affected by animation(It collapses and expanded to original size again). Other animation types work as expected.

```
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

if (changes.insertedSectionsIndexes.count > 0) {
    [self.tableView insertSections:changes.insertedSectionsIndexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
}

[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: what you want to do ? add new row or add selection data ?

Comment: Just like I wrote: if top section(with one or more rows) inserted using UITableViewRowAnimationTop, tableHeaderView redraws although I don't see why it should be related - it's just uiview on top on uitableview.

Comment: at one time only one row inserted in table .\